# How to stream videos in WPF?

Tags: wpf, video-streaming, vlc, mediaelement

I want to stream video in a WPF application. There are two potential ways:

1. Embed VLC. Problem: I know how to embed VLC in a WinForm application but not in a WPF one.
2. Use MediaElement. Problem: I know how to play a wmv file, but I don't know how to play a stream.

So what can I do to play video streams in WPF?

Comment: Does Embed Vlc mean active plugin x?

Comment: @Salih: Yes, VLC ActiveX Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy task. You can find out VlcDotnet. it's open source and using the VLC libraries. This is the Github link. It is fit with WPF.

[Source File](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)